# Как участники сети блокчейн проверяют валидность приватного ключа?

Tags: bitcoin, криптовалюта, блокчейн

Извините, если вопрос слишком глупый, но погуглив - я не нашёл на него ответа, надеюсь что вы мне поможете.
Я пытаюсь разобраться как работает блокчейн. И узнал вот что. Каждая транзакция содержит в себе приватный ключ, который является подписью транзакции, и гарантирует то, что монеты принадлежат именно вам. Вот у меня несколько вопросов по этому поводу. Раз блокчейн прозрачен, то почему нельзя посмотреть приватный ключ в блоке? Скорее всего он там не в открытом виде, но тогда следующий вопрос: **как участники сети проверяют его валидность?** Ведь если бы его можно было сгенерировать заново, он бы потерял свой смысл, но как тогда он проверяется?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я блокчейн не трогал, но все такие системы работаю примерно одинаково. Даже https на этом сайте. https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!